# Setting up background img with angular 7

Tags: angular, github-pages

I have a problem with displaying background img in angular. I am using function with ngStyle in html tag and it works fine, but when i upload whole project on github pages imgs with this method doesn't show up. Other images that i add with img tag works fine. Could help me fix it ?

Code:

```js
getHeaderBackgroundImg() {
    return `url(/assets/images/4.jpg)`
  }
```

```html
<header [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getHeaderBackgroundImg(), 'background-position' : 'center', 'height' : '950px', 'width' : '100%'}" class="main__container"></header>
```

Answer (score 1):

remove `/` from the beginning of your path (relativity)

```
getDescriptionBackgroundImg() {
    return `url(assets/images/4.jpg)`
  }
```

Comment: Just pushed this changes on git and still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
getDescriptionBackgroundImg() {
    return `url(assets/images/4.jpg)`
  }

<header [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getDescriptionBackgroundImg(), 'background-position' : 'center', 'height' : '950px', 'width' : '100%'}" class="main__container"></header>
```

Comment: It was just a type mistake